# Why is my keyboard not functioning when I load my PC causing it to swap upto 2GB of memory?

Tags: linux, memory, keyboard, swap

I have a below avarage laptop with 6GB RAM (I know it should be either 4GB or 8GB for optimisation reasons and such but I gotta work with what I got) and about 1GB of it is used up by my desktop environment; this is deepin. So when running Android Studio (in the process of learning the software) and chrome for tutorials, my laptop will have 90+% usage of RAM and over 1GB and sometimes near 2GB of swap memmory being used. I'm fine with that but I've noticed so oddities like my keyboard not working, the dock with my apps not working, keyboard shortcuts not working when my keyboard is, etc. All of these are fixed when I close Android Studio and run `sudo swapoff -a && sudo swapon -a`.

I think that some of these processes that handle such inputs are being swapped out but I'm not sure of it since I'm relatively new to Linux and do not understand every aspect of how Linux swaps. I'm on Manjaro Linux is that helps

Edit: Laptop Config:
CPU: Intel i5-3230M Dual core, 4 threads
For chipset, I ran `sudo dmidecode | grep -A4 'Base Board Information'` and the output is as follows:

```
Base Board Information
    Manufacturer: LENOVO
    Product Name: 2320JPU
    Version: 0B98401 Pro
    Serial Number: 1ZSSX3BE2CU
```

Comment: 6 GB vs 8 GB doesn't make much difference. Perhaps 2-3% gain in CPU performance if you can run dual-channel, but it makes no difference for swapping performance. What is more important to troubleshoot your problem is to know what CPU and motherboard chipset you have. This sounds like you have only 2 cores and slow CPU. Please edit your question and add more details on your laptops exact specifications.

Comment: @Tonny Updated the question as per your request :)

Comment: That machine is a Lenovo X230. I have one here in the basement running Windows 10 V2004.  It has 16 GB of memory. Are you sure you cannot add memory to accommodate many Chrome tabs?

Comment: @John I'm really keen on spending anymore money on this laptop as it's lifespan is coming to an end. I'll probably be getting a new laptop in a couple of months so until then, I want to try to solve this issue. I'm also curious as to what causes this and how to deal with it. In the future, is there is a server I want to configure that has swap but a specific process sholdn't be swapped, I'd wanna know what to do.

Comment: Try a session without using Chrome and see if the memory swap problem remains

Comment: @John Though choppy when switching windows and/or virtual desktops (obviously swapping), the problem is not yet appeared after I have run `echo 1 > /proc/sys/vm/swapiness`(was at 60 prior). Though I don't think this is a permanent solution, I am getting "better" performance. Been running Android Studio with 3 chrome tabs, one with YouTube and also chrome has a few extensions as well as htop in a terminal and ~800MB of swap is being used. I'm wondering, since I have 5.7GB of swap allocated, would deceasing the size of the swap partition do any good since I'm never using all of it anyways?

Comment: I think the overall problem is related to limited memory. You can try reducing the swap partition size to see if that helps. I am not certain.

Comment: @John If I run into the same problem again, I'll try to reduce it. Thanks for your insight